# Sum of array elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, scripting

I'm trying to solve this problem where I initialize an array of 5 elements and print the sum of the elements. I can't wrap my head around the logic behind the solution. Please review my code.

Another problem with reading an array of 5 integers and printing the smallest element. I keep getting the wrong answer...

This's a script embedded inside an HTML file.

**Problem 1**

```
var num= [1,1,1,1]; 

var total=num[0];
for( var i=0 ; i < num.length ; i++)
    { 

     total =+num[i]; 
    }


window.alert("The total is "+ total);
```

I expected the answer to be 4, but all I get is 1.

---

**Problem 2**

```
var r = new Array(5);

var len = r.length; 

for(var i=0 ; i <len ; i++)
    {
        r[i] = window.prompt("Enter the elements of the array");
    }


 var small= [0];

for(var j=0; j< len ; j++)
    { 
     if(r[i] < small )
         small = r[i];
    }

window.alert("The smallest element is the array is "+small);
```

I get the last element in my array as the smallest element which's obviously isn't right.

Comment: In the first problem, shouldn't the ```var total=num[0]``` be ```var total = 0```?

Comment: `total += num[i];` instead of `total = +num[i];` for the first problem and `var small = r[0];` instead of `var small = [0];` for the second one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In problem 1) you just need to change =+ to +=

In problem 2) you need to start in the first element of `r` and in the for loop you need index the `r` array by the variable `j` instead of `i` variable

```
var r = new Array(5);
var len = r.length; 

for(var i=0 ; i <len ; i++)
{
    r[i] = window.prompt("Enter the elements of the array");
}

var small = r[0];

for( var j=0; j< len ; j++)
{ 
    if(r[j] < small )
        small = r[j];
}

window.alert("The smallest element is the array is "+small);
```

**But you could just do:**

```
const min = Math.min(...r)
window.alert("The smallest element is the array is "+ min);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things here.

For problem 1:
Since you initialize the `total` to the first item I think you end up counting it 2 times. Likely you'd want to initialize to 0. `var total = 0`. 
You will also want to use `+=` instead of `=+` the latter sets the value instead of adding it.

For Problem 2:
`new Array(5)` creates a new sparse array. It's kinda weird. It's like it's full of `undefined` values.  So when you assign `small` you'll want to access the first element of `r`, `var small = r[0]` but that will be `undefined` due to `r` being a sparse array. So you'll want `var r = new Array(5).fill().map((x,i) => i)` to set values in that array. You will also want to use `j` instead of `i` in the body of the second loop.

That should do it ;).

Comment: Thank you, but what's the use of .fill() and map?? can you explain this code for me? var r = new Array(5).fill().map((x,i) => i)

Answer (score 0):

Hi The problem 1 could be tackled with reduce method check the Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

The problem 2 could be solved with Math.min method:

```
var num= [1,1,1,1]; 
var numMin= [100,1121,1212,122, 12]; 

//Problem1
let totalSum = num.reduce( ( accumulator, currentItem ) => {
 return accumulator = accumulator += currentItem;
} , 0 );

console.log(totalSum)

//Problem 2
console.log( 'Min',Math.min( ...numMin ) );
```

Here is a [replit](https://repl.it/repls/FirstItchyAdware) so you can play with the code

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Find array elements sum

let total = 0;
let arr = [1,2,3,4];

arr.map(el => total+=el);

console.log(total); // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Find array smallest element

let arr = [1,-2,13,-4,7];

let smlEl = arr[0]

arr.map(el => {
  if(el < smlEl) {
    smlEl = el;
  }
})

console.log(smlEl); // -4
```